# elegant way to code if/elif/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, pep8

```
indepgroupl = ['numerical', 'categorical']
        
depgroupl = ["numerical", "categorical", "factors", "count"]
        
for i in indepgroupl:
  for j in depgroupl:
      if i == 'categorical':
          if i == 'numerical':
              if j == 'numerical':
                 print("utter_indepnumcat_depnum")
               elif j == 'categorical':
                 print("utter_indepnumcat_depcat")
               elif j == 'time to event':
                 print("utter_indepnumcat_deptimetoevent")
               if j == 'numerical':
                  print("utter_indep2cat_depnum")
       elif i == 'factors':
           if j == 'count':
              print("utter_indepfac_depcount")
           elif j == 'numerical':
              print("utter_indepfac_depnum")
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this if/elif/else loop? Can I use list comprehension for this?

Comment: Isn't the logic wrong? How can I be both categorical and numerical or factors at same time?

Or is it just an example?

Comment: There are an awful lot of mistakes in this code ~ no matter what `i` is, this code will never do anything.

Comment: @Msvstl..apologies. Syntax error. I have corrected it. My intention is to code that independent group elements could be either 'categorical' or 'numerical' or both or 'factors"

Comment: Sorry for the awfully wrong code @OneMadGypsy. Will work on improving it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the conditional value and the string to print in a tupled list

```
for cat, val in [('numerical', 'depnum'), ('categorical', 'depcat'), ('time to event', 'deptimetoevent')]:
    if i == cat:
        print ('utter_indepnumcat_' + val)
```

For just three entries you don't save much lines of code; it makes more sense if you have more entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using a switch-like syntax. If you are using python v3.10+ you can utilize the match and case syntax as detailed [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-switch-statement-switch-case-example/).